# Can we show $\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\sup_{0<\left\|x-y\right\|_E<\varepsilon}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{\left\|x-y\right\|_E}=\left\|{\rm D}f(x)\right\|_{E'}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, frechet-derivative

Let $f:E\to\mathbb R$ be Fréchet differentiable and $x\in E$. By definition, $$\lim_{y\to x}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)-{\rm D}f(x)(x-y)|}{\left\|x-y\right\|_E}=0.\tag1$$ Can we somehow (maybe by imposing a further suitable assumption) show that $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\sup_{\substack{y\in E\\0<\left\|x-y\right\|_E<\varepsilon}}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{\left\|x-y\right\|_E}=\left\|{\rm D}f(x)\right\|_{E'}\tag2?$$

Comment: Assuming that $\left\|{\rm D}f(x)\right\| =\left\|{\rm D}f(x)(v)\right\|$ for some $v$ is too much for you? Does it is enough?

Comment: @RenanWillianPrado Well, this is the case whenever $E$ is finite-dimensional (since then the closed unit ball is compact), but I'm interested in infinite-dimensional $E$ only. Let me note that I've found a similar claim (for arbitrary $E$) in the proof of Lemma 4.2 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0602479.pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $E$ is a Banach space, and $u \colon E \to \mathbb{R}$ is a
bounded linear functional, then for all $\delta > 0,$
$$
\|u\| = \sup_{\|x\| = 1}|u(x)| =
\sup_{\|h\| = \delta}
\left\lvert{u}\left(\frac{h}{\|h\|}\right)\right\rvert =
\sup_{\|h\| = \delta}\frac{|u(h)|}{\|h\|}.
$$
Therefore for all $\varepsilon > 0,$
\begin{equation}
\label{3708359:eq:3}\tag{3}
\|u\| = \sup_{0 < \|h\| < \varepsilon}\frac{|u(h)|}{\|h\|}.
\end{equation}

If $U$ is an open subset of $E,$ and $f \colon U \to \mathbb{R}$ is
differentiable at $x \in U,$ then the function
$$
d \colon U - x \to \mathbb{R}, \
h \mapsto f(x + h) - f(x) - f'(x)(h)
$$
satisfies the condition
$$
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{d(h)}{\|h\|} = 0.
$$
Take any $\eta > 0,$ and take $\varepsilon > 0$ such that if
$\|h\| < \varepsilon$ then $x + h \in U$ and
$$
|d(h)| \leqslant \eta\|h\|.
$$

If $x + h \in U,$ then by the Triangle Inequality,
$$
||f(x + h) - f(x)| - |f'(x)(h)|| \leqslant
|f(x + h) - f(x) - f'(x)(h)| = |d(h)|.
$$
Therefore, if $0 < \|h\| < \varepsilon,$
$$
\left\lvert \frac{|f(x + h) - f(x)|}{\|h\|} -
\frac{|f'(x)(h)|}{\|h\|} \right\rvert \leqslant \eta.
$$

Take any $\varepsilon^*$ such that $0 < \varepsilon^* < \varepsilon,$
and let
$$
N(\varepsilon^*) = \{h \in E : 0 < \|h\| < \varepsilon^* \}.
$$
For $h \in N(\varepsilon^*),$ the inequality just proved has the form
$$
|p(h) - q(h)| \leqslant \eta,
$$
for certain functions
$$
p, q \colon N(\varepsilon^*) \to \mathbb{R}_{\geqslant 0}.
$$
By \eqref{3708359:eq:3}, the function $q(h) = |f'(x)(h)|/\|h\|$ is bounded on $N(\varepsilon^*),$ and
$$
\sup_{h \in N(\varepsilon^*)}q(h) = \|f'(x)\|.
$$
Therefore, the function $p(h) = |f(x + h) - f(x)|/\|h\|$ is also bounded
on $N(\varepsilon^*),$ and
$$
\left\lvert \sup_{0 < \|h\| < \varepsilon^*}
\frac{|f(x + h) - f(x)|}{\|h\|} - \|f'(x)\| \right\rvert
\leqslant \eta.
$$
This holds for arbitrary $\eta$ and for all $\varepsilon^*$ such that
$0 < \varepsilon^* < \varepsilon,$ where $\varepsilon$ depends on $\eta,$
therefore
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0+} \sup_{0 < \|h\| < \varepsilon}
\frac{|f(x + h) - f(x)|}{\|h\|} = \|f'(x)\|.
$$

Comment: Please note that in your first displayed equation $\varepsilon$ is not occurring.

Comment: Yes, I rewrote that part of the answer hastily to correct a serious error after being awake all night, so it's not very elegant! It isn't strictly incorrect (because "for all $\varepsilon$" applies to the whole paragraph including $\eqref{3708359:eq:3}$), but I'll rewrite it again if there is ever any serious need to edit the answer. Or perhaps even if there is no serious need! $\ddot\smile$

Comment: The introduction of the set $N$ is an unnecessary and unsightly complication. I should just have written $N = U - x.$ (Arguably I should have stuck closer to your notation!) It's worth a rewrite to get rid of these two flaws, but I'll wait and see if any more are identified in the next few hours.

Comment: I have tidied up both those details. I have also expanded the argument, at one point. (I'd left that point murkily implicit before, because there were too many other details to think about at the time.) I hope I haven't garbled anything in the process - let me know if I have.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{v_n\}$ be such that $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \|Df(x)(v_n)\|=\|Df(x)\|$ and $\|v_n\|=1$ for all $n$. Then, by definition, choosing $t_n \rightarrow 0$, we have
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{|f(x+t_n v_n)-f(x)|}{|t_n|}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|Df(x)(v_n)|=\|Df(x)\|.$$ Hence, 
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\sup_{\substack{y\in E\\0<\left\|x-y\right\|_E<\varepsilon}}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{\left\|x-y\right\|_E} \geq \left\|{\rm D}f(x)\right\|.$$ Suppose, by contradiction, that 
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\sup_{\substack{y\in E\\0<\left\|x-y\right\|_E<\varepsilon}}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{\left\|x-y\right\|_E} > \left\|{\rm D}f(x)\right\|.$$ Then, choosing $\{u_n\}\subset E$ and $\{t_n\}$ such that $\|u_n\|=1$ for all $n$, $t_n\rightarrow 0$ and
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\sup_{\substack{y\in E\\0<\left\|x-y\right\|_E<\varepsilon}}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{\left\|x-y\right\|_E} = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{|f(x+t_n u_n)-f(x)|}{|t_n|},$$ we get
$$\|Df(x)(u_n)\| = \dfrac{\|\left( f(x+t_n u_n)- f(x)\right)-\left(-Df(x)(t_n u_n)+ f(x+t_n u_n)-f(x)\right)\|}{|t_n|} \geq  $$
$$ \dfrac{\|f(x+t_n u_n)-f(x)\| - \| f(x+t_n u_n)- f(x)-Df(x)(t_n u_n)\|}{|t_n|}.$$ Finelly, for large enough $n$,
$$
\|Df(x)(u_n)\|> \|Df(x)\|.
$$ A contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why can you find the sequence $\{v_n\}$?

Comment: If A is a subset of real numbers, then I can find a sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that $a_n \rightarrow \sup A.$ The proof is based on the fact that $\sup$ is the smallest upper bound for A. Hence, if $a<\sup A$, I can find $x$ on $A$ such that $a<x< \sup A$ otherwise, $x$ is a smaller upper bound. I did the same for $u_n$.

Comment: Yes, sure. I know understand why these sequences exist. But, in the first part, how precisely do you conclude $$\liminf_{\varepsilon\to0+}\sup_{\substack{h\in E\\0<\left\|h\right\|_E<\varepsilon}}\frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)|}{\left\|h\right\|_E} \geq \left\|{\rm D}f(x)\right\|$$ (which should be what we need to conclude here)?

Comment: It's true that : $$\sup_{\substack{y\in E\\0<\left\|x-y\right\|_E<t_n}}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{\left\|x-y\right\|_E} \geq \frac{|f(x+t_n v_n)-f(x)|}{|t_n|} $$